# Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint does not return correct position

Tags: unity

I have a cube in the center of my camera view, when I call `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position)` I expect to get the same result as if I called `new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0))`. But its not even close, why?

```
Debug.Log("1: " + new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
Debug.Log("2: " + Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: My first suspicion was this might be due to DPI scaling on a high-resolution display, but I've just tested this on a 4K monitor with scaling activated and I'm still getting a perfect match between the calculated value and the one returned by `WorldToScreenPoint`. Can you walk us through the steps to build a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, starting from a new, empty project? Make sure the only object running this script is the one instance in front of the camera, and that it's running *after* any screen resizing due to e.g. the "Maximize on Play" setting.